# drawRect depends on Views -> On Startup Custom View uses wrong frames

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, drawrect

My view hierachy looks like this: (I use `Autolayout`)

- `ContentView`

  - `CustomView` (implements `drawRect`)
  - `Button`
  - `TableView`

In the `drawRect` of the `CustomView` I draw a `UIBezierPath` from the top to the bottom through all `CustomView.SuperView.subViews` where the line stops if a `Frame` is in the way and begins to draw further till the next frame and so on.

On `Startup` when the `DrawRect` is called the `Views` are not finished with layouting I guess, because the frames I get from the views are not correct.

The Problem is solved if I call

```
customView.setNeedsLayout()
customView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

in the `ViewDidAppear` method. But this impacts performance cause it gets called twice.
What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a violation of the principle [*tell, don't ask*](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask). You should be *tell*ing your view where to draw; it shouldn't be *ask*ing.

Inside `CustomView`:

- Get rid of any calls to `self.superview`.
- Add a property that represents the information you need to draw (like `@property NSArray *framesToSkip`)
- In `drawRect:` look in your property for the information you need.

In your view controller:

- In `viewWillLayoutSubviews:`, update your custom view's `framesToSkip` property with the appropriate views.
- If needed, call `setNeedsDisplay` on your custom view.

---

A few general rules that, if broken, indicate you might be violating *tell, don't ask*:

- Never access a view's `superview`.
- Never access a view controller's `parentViewController` or `presentingViewController`.
- Never import a view controller class unless it's your child / presented view controller.

Comment: Um why do you think it's wrong to access the superview? A view has a lot of things it should never do when superview is nil.

Comment: In particular to do with having a proper context within which to draw.

Comment: @uchuugaka `drawRect:` will not be called if there is no proper context.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBrager! My initial problem was that i was doing some layouting after the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is being called.

Comment: Not sure if it's actually always true. There are scenarios where people get things trying to render to an invalid context and spew to the console. Plenty of SO posts. Generally it is drawing or animating before the view is properly in the view hierarchy.

Comment: @uchuugaka That's usually due to a programmer error. (I usually see that when people try multithreading in `drawRect:` or don't call the designated initializer.) Anyway, I don't mean "literally never do this stuff", I mean "never do this stuff without intentionally breaking tell, don't ask for a very good reason".

Comment: Fair. Yes. Drawing or animating from background threads or modifying state there without synchronizing usually is the culprit.